# spring-data-elasticsearch with MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I want to ask if it is possible to use spring-data-elasticsearch in conjonction with  Mysql Database. For example the store of items will be with this flow elastic-search <==> spring-data  <==> Mysql Database

Answer (score 6):

My solution is, define the entity as `document` like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Document(indexName = "user")
public class User {....}
```

Define a `UserRepository` of `spring-data`,  and a `UserSearchRepository` of spring-data-elasticSearch separately.

When I create a new user, add index with `UserSearchRepository.save(user)` at the same time. Do the same when update or delete.

Answer (score 0):

No You can not use ***Spring Data Elasticsearch*** to do your database operations on ***MySQL***.
The name itself states that this ***Spring Data*** Technology is an implementation for the ***Elasticsearch***. 
To do the Database part you will require a Java persistence technology(eg. *Hibernate*)